# Android use cache for saving images

Tags: android, image, caching

The basic idea is that: I'm downloading encrypted image file from internet and start decrypting it.

After it's done I want to save it to the cache (if this is the best way to do what I need) and than load it in a lazy loading listview.

But for now I just want to test the showing image after decryption in an ImageView.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
package com.android.basetableview;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class BaseTableViewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        Bitmap myBitmap = getBitmapFromURL("http://pu-twitter.netau.net/card1.png");
        imgView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }


    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = null;
            try {

                URL url = new URL(src);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();

                //Decryption
                try {
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
                SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec("01234567890abcde".getBytes(), "AES");
                IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec("fedcba9876543210".getBytes());
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(input, cipher);
                FileOutputStream fos  = new FileOutputStream(
                           new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "card2_decrypted.jpg"));
                byte[] b = new byte[8];
                int i;

                while ((i = cis.read(b)) != -1) {
                  fos.write(b, 0, i);
                }
                fos.flush(); fos.close();
                cis.close(); input.close();


                //myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.fillInStackTrace();
                    Log.v("ERROR","Errorchence : "+e);
                }

                return myBitmap;


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
}
```

As you can see, I'm saving the decrypted image in sdcard, but the images that I'm using are small and maybe the cache will be better option. So if you guys can give me some advice how can I do that and which is the best way to save the images and then show them as a content in a ImageView.

Comment: Aha since it is working well :) Keep it this way

Comment: actually it's not working right now,because in this code I'm not setting the myBitmap.Actually I don't prefer to save the images in sdcard,that's why I want to save them in cache.Any suggestions how to save it in cache and than convert it to bitmap,so I can use it?

Comment: you dont want to save them for future usage? You prefer to keep them in cache?

Comment: Yeah, my idea is to download the images everytime a user wants to see them.I don't need the images to be saved in sdcard.That's why I want to save them in cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK you don't need to save the images:

```
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = null;
            try {

                URL url = new URL(src);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();

                //Decryption
                try {
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
                SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec("01234567890abcde".getBytes(), "AES");
                IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec("fedcba9876543210".getBytes());
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(input, cipher);


                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cis);

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.fillInStackTrace();
                    Log.v("ERROR","Errorchence : "+e);
                }

                return myBitmap;


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: you are sure of the `String src` and the `Cipher` parameters?

Comment: Yep, It's working,decrypting and etc,but isn't it better if I save the decrypted image in cache?So if user switch to another activity and when he return back to previous one,the images are still loaded?

Comment: ok listen this code is returning a bitmap! Now we want to keep a container for these bitmaps where all the activities of this application can use it .. right?

Comment: No,my idea is to use these bitmaps after that as elements of lazy list.And when they are loaded in lazy list(all the images) I need to be able to reload the images.So if I have 300images in that lazy list,when 50 of them are loaded I want to delete the first loaded images and start loading the next visible ones.That's why I think I need to save them in cache.Sorry for the poorly specified question.

Comment: Listen Do a new question stating that we have a function `public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src)` (don't show its source code) and discuss what do you need from the listview.. I will answer

Comment: Hope, this time is more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a ImageView to show the image. second the imageview can accept a Bitmap, a resource or an URI. but bitmap is the best because using an uri and resource means the decoding of the image before its placed happens in the ui thread which is not a good thing to do for images.

for setting the image bitmap, get the reference to your imageview in your layout and use

```
myImageView.setImageBitmap(myImageBitmap);
```

to get an image bitmap from SD card you can use BitmapFactory.decodeFile(); function for example. i usually decode images to bitmaps straight from the stream from the internet and then save the bitmap as file on SD. i believe thats a better solution.

```
File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Bitmap bmp;
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(inputStream));
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, outStream);
```

where i am using the function flushed input stream because of a bug in the url connection. see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339082/android-decoder-decode-returned-false-for-bitmap-download)

as for a cache you can definitely use the sdcard. its a lot better than using the phones memory for that (thats the cache dir on the phone which fills the phone memory), you can just clear the sd cache by removing all the images in your cache folder onDestroy(). its simple. and if you like a in-Memory cache then use a hashMap, weakReference or a softReference map. i suggest for longer storage a hashMap but be careful with the memory consumption.

for "Lazy Loading" images [see this link](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)