# Getting Bitmap null while loading it from Url in the for loop

Tags: android, url, bitmap

I am using following code snippet to load url to bitmap in for loop. It gives null value to bitmap sometimes.So what could be the proper solution to get bitmap value for each loop??

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        String url = "image url"+i;
        try {
            URL url2 = new URL(url);
            InputStream inputStream = url2.openConnection()
                    .getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            Log.i("@@@@@@@@@@ bitmap", "" + bitmap);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InputStream may have problems when the network connection is not stable,which leads to null return value for BitmapFactory.decodeStream().I had also encountered this problem. 
Algo has created a FlushedInputStream class, which solves my problem, it may help you

```
 static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        super(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
        while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
            long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
            if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                int b = read();
                if (b < 0) {
                    break;  // we reached EOF
                } else {
                    bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                }
            }
            totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
        }
        return totalBytesSkipped;
    }
}
```

original post : [Android decoder->decode returned false for Bitmap download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339082/android-decoder-decode-returned-false-for-bitmap-download)

Answer (score 0):

Friends...I have got the solution for this...I have just added few lines as following...it works nice....

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        String url = "image url";
        try {
            URL url2 = new URL(url);
            InputStream inputStream = url2.openConnection()
                    .getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            Log.i("@@@@@@@@@@ bitmap", "" + bitmap);
            if(bitmap== null) {
                i--;
                continue;
            }
            bitmap_array.add(bitmap);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

1 more thing you need to add is to check Net Connection in loop.

and Also check for inputStream is null or not, there you can break the loop.

Comment: Just a headsup; this can cause infinite loops in cases where the url is incorrect or does not lead to a proper image.