# Error with decoder in Bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a problem with decode my bitmap. This is my code:

```
public static Bitmap loadujSmallBitmapeczke(File file) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
        int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
        int imageWidth = options.outWidth;

        options.inSampleSize=4;

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;


        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
    }
```

here where I use to get images from sd card:

```
public class ServiceImages1 extends LinearLayout{
    public ServiceImages1(Context context, String id) {
        super(context);
        init(id);
    }
    public ServiceImages1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, String id) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(id);
    }
    private void init(String id) {
        File file;
        file = new File("/sdcard/DinEgen/"+id);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        //imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(HejSokolyLadujBMP.loadujSmallBitmapeczke(file)); 



        addView(imageView);
    }
}
```

where id is name my image.

and I get error: `decoder->decode returned false`. How I can fix this? Where is problem?

Edit: I my pictures are on sd card, so I can't use solution with URL. Only what I goth is path to file.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339082/android-decoder-decode-returned-false-for-bitmap-download

Comment: this is not dupplicate. Solution from your link doesn't work for me because I have my images on sd card and I have only path to the file

Comment: finally your problem get solved or not?

Comment: no. I have still the same problem

Comment: Which kind of image format do you use? PNG? JPEG? Also have you made sure that you can open the images correctly with another app? Try to download them on your pc and open them. Is this possible? Where does the images come from? Do you download them directly via your own code? Is there another error/stacktrace, too?

Comment: I use PNG, JPEG, JPG. In other example it work great with this formats. I open that files without problems on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
byte[] byteimage = file.toByteArray(); // I dont know whether toByteArray() will work        
   // or not Some how convert your file into byte[]

BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inDither = true;
opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap rebitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteimage,0,byteimage.length, opt);

return rebitmap;
```