# Progressive jpeg on Android

Tags: android

Does Android platform support progressive **JPEG**? I can see from [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) that platform supports both Baseline and Progressive.

But when i try to create bitmap from progressive bytes, it always throw error like

```
D/skia(16136): --- decoder->decode returned false
```

Until the last chunk with EOI is added. Which makes the progressive JPEG concept is useless with Android Bitmap.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the file which you try to decode?

Comment: You can try the answers of this link:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339082/android-decoder-decode-returned-false-for-bitmap-download][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339082/android-decoder-decode-returned-false-for-bitmap-download