# Decode error when downloading image from URL

Tags: android

I'm trying to download some images from urls but I keep getting a decode error for each image it tries to download. Here is my code in which I want to add the downloaded images to an array of classes.

```
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 

                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                Programme Progresult = new Programme();

                Progresult.name = json_data.getString("name");
                Progresult.event = json_data.getString("event");
                Progresult.price = json_data.getString("price");


                String imageurl = json_data.getString("preview");
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageurl).getContent());
                Progresult.progpreview = bitmap;


                arraydata.add(Progresult);

                }
            }
            catch(JSONException e1){ 

                }
            catch (ParseException e1) { 
                e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return arraydata;
                }
```

Here is the log cat error that I am getting for each image.....

```
06-19 13:44:26.550: D/skia(722): --- decoder->decode returned false
```

And here is a url of an image that I'm trying to download

```
http://ec2-54-228-87-185.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/corkgaa/Matchprogrammes/sample3.bmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this--->

```
  URL url = new URL(imageurl);
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
  conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
  conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
  conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
  InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
  is.close();
  conn.disconnect();
```

Comment: go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339082/android-decoder-decode-returned-false-for-bitmap-download)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try some of them